# mock.record exception

Tags: testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I am using `mock.record()` and I am checking the length of a filename..
The test code is:

```
        MockRepository mock = new MockRepository();
        IExtension ext = mock.StrictMock<IExtension>();

        using (mock.Record())
        {
            ext.LogError("filename not valid");
        }

        LogAnalyser log = new LogAnalyser(ext);
        string shortfilename = "jjh.df";
        log.IsValid(shortfilename);
        mock.Verify(ext);
```

and the production code is:

```
    public void IsValid(string filename)
    {
        if(filename.Length<8)
        {
            extension.LogError("filename is short:" + filename);
        }
    }
```

On debugging, the `extension.logerror` in production gives an exception:

```
IExtension.LogError("filename is short:jjh.df"); Expected #0, Actual #1.
IExtension.LogError("filename not valid"); Expected #1, Actual #0.
```

please provide some solution.

Answer (score 1):

The LogError is hit more then one time. Add the following:

> ext.LogError("filename not
>   valid").IgnoreArguments().Repeat.Any();

I am not 100% sure if you need the

Comment: .IgnoreArgument is not working..It is showing an error 'cannot resolve symbol "ignoreargument'..

Answer (score 0):

You're using a StrictMock which means only calls specifically set up by you are allowed -- and that includes the values of the parameters.  You set an expectation that a call would be made to LogError with the string:

```
filename not valid
```

But what actually happened during execution was a call was made with the string:

```
filename is short:jjh.df
```

So Rhino.Mocks gives you the two exceptions (one because it found a call that wasn't expected and the other because an expected call was not found).

@Ivo's response of using "IgnoreArguments" should work.  If it's not, please include more details as to what version of .NET and Rhino.Mocks you're using.